# VB.NET - Shell batch file vs. Manually opening batch file = different results, for PSFTP.exe

Tags: vb.net, batch-file, ssis, sftp

I am using a Script Task in SSIS.  So I am writing in vb.net.  I have a substantial amount of code that ends up writing two files:  one is a .bat file with this EXACT contents in it, minus I've changed **hostname**, **username**, and **password** of course:

```
C:\Users\ipisors\AppData\Local\Temp\091014121929_Phoenix\psftp.exe -pw PASSWORD -b C:\Users\ipisors\AppData\Local\Temp\091014121929_Phoenix\091014121929.txt USERNAME@HOST
```

(I'm sure it has this, because I manually check it after the Script Task runs).

The content of the .txt file referenced in the command is this EXACTLY:

```
cd uploads
cd OUT
mget PhoenixEnrollment_20140910*.txt
bye
```

**MY QUESTION** -

After the script task runs successfully, there is no downloaded file inside the directory of PSFTP.EXE (C:\Users\ipisors\AppData\Local\Temp\091014121929_Phoenix).  Nothing.
However, if I manually double click on that same batch file that the script task was supposed to SHELL(), it immediately works perfectly.  Within a few seconds, there is a downloaded file inside C:\Users\ipisors\AppData\Local\Temp\091014121929_Phoenix

What could possibly be the difference in reaction from the FTP server, between my script task code:

```
Shell(strBatPhoenix, AppWinStyle.NormalFocus, True)
```

(which by the way - yes I can actually see it working!)
and double clicking the same da*n file
I've also debugged the script task, it's definition Shelling out the EXACT SAME bat file.
Help please!
I will say the password to the SFTP site has a caret (^) in it, which I am escaping by using a double caret.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out after additionally testing one other way:

I used the command prompt itself to run my batch file.  It ALSO did not download to the expected directory.  I began to suspect that, even though the Shell was automating a batch file in the 'desired' folder......that batch file was then reading the 'local' directory as whatever calling application had initially Shelled it out.

In this case:  c:\users\myusername.  And therein was my file.

Lesson to be learned:  Shelling a batch file, even if that batch file shells another file, may end up with one application or another reading your instant directory as the instant directory of the application that did the first shell, not the last shell.